# What does motivational quote mean?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

> Jyn: Saw Gerrera used to say...**one fighter with a sharp stick and
> nothing left to lose can take the day**.

What does motivational quote mean?

Comment: This point is illustrated in a subsequent film; https://us-east-1.linodeobjects.com/gunaxin/2013/05/Ewok_ERJ-560x318.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply that motivation can be a deciding factor in conflict.

A determined fighter that has, "Nothing left to lose," may be at a disadvantage in terms of equipment, training, numbers, or any other military factor but can still win simply because they are willing to take risks in combat that their opponents wouldn't take or wouldn't expect that fighter to take. That fighter may die, but their actions can still result in a win, and the desperate nature of their circumstances mean that sacrifice is seen as worthwhile.

This is demonstrated during the climatic battle where the Rebels, definitely disadvantaged in terms of manpower and materiel compared to the Empire are able to "win" at Scarif despite the horrendous losses they suffer, simply because the existence of the Death Star means they have nothing left to lose and they fight to the last. The entirety of Rogue One die during that operation, but their actions save the galaxy.

Real world comparisons can be seen in the fact that the motto of many military organisation and especially special forces groups around the world play on similar motifs. Perhaps the most famous example being the SAS's, "Who Dares Wins," motto.

Comment: "They are fighting for their king, we are fighting for our children", etc. This has happened over and over again, both on fiction, and in history.